# Database/algorithm for rideshare reservation

Tags: algorithm, google-maps, recursion, logic, combinations

I'm working on a small ridesharing website, where people can create their routes with stopovers using google maps API (latitude and longitude).

I can create all the possible combinations on a given route (including stopovers) like in this answer:

[(Java) Find all possible pairs in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392652/java-find-all-possible-pairs-in-an-array)

Example: If a journey going from A to D has 2 stopovers (B and C), there will be 6 possible 'journeys':

1. City A - City D (longest trip)
2. City A - City C (trip with all-1 stops)
3. City B - City D (trip with all-1 stops)
4. City A - City B (no stopovers on this one)
5. City B - City C (no stopovers on this one)
6. City C - City D (no stopovers on this one)

When a passenger books a seat on a given journey, some of the other journeys will get a seat booked as well, according to their position in the 'pyramid'.

**I haven't found a way to programatically determine which journeys will be affected (or not) when a seat is booked on any given trip.**

The closest ideas I've found are a bus booking script from phpjabbers and this SO answer:
[Database design for bus reservation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10096250/database-design-for-bus-reservation)
, however those two solutions already have the cities/stops stored on the DB, while in "my" solution the stops are always dynamic (using google maps API).

So far I've tried:

- Creating a kind of EAV relationship between the journeys and a 'master' journey.
- Creating like 'levels' according to the quantity of stopovers (level 1 is the longest trip, level 2 are journeys with n-1 stopovers and so on.
- Trying to play with a matrix according to the start point/end point.

I'm not addressing the problem in the right way (of course) but I'm not sure if this question is related to mathematics, algorithms or anything else. Please excuse me about that.

I'd like to get and idea on how to address this problem: a formula, algorithm, some basic code or whatever.

EDIT:

To explain better the problem, this would be a typical scenario:

1. The Driver creates a ride from A to D with three seats available. The Driver adds two stopovers, in B and C. It generates 6 journeys (see above).

The four points or cities (A,B,C,D) are chosen from the google maps api so they are not stored locally. The latitude and longitude of each point are 'attached' to the rides.

2. Passenger Z books a seat on the longest ride (#1). Now all the rides have only two seats available. Easy enough.
3. Passenger Y books a seat on the ride #6 (from C to D). Now the rides #1, #3 and #6 have one seat less available (2 occupied, 1 available).
4. Passenger X books a seat on the ride #2 (from A to C). **This is where it becomes complex.** Now the rides #2, #4 and #5 have one seat less available (1 occupied, 2 available), the same applies to #3 (2 occupied, 1 available).

**At this point even if 3 passengers have booked seats on 'sub-rides', ride #1 still has 1 seat available** (see above point 3). This is my problem, I don't know how to determine that ride #1 mustn't be modified by the booking of Passenger X (point 4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer lies in storing a journey from A to D with stop-overs in B and C as 3 seperate legs right from the start, and seperately storing the complete ride, with links back and forth between ride and legs. (Ignore combined legs like AC or BD.)

> RIDES TABLE:
>   ride: {id=1, from: "New York", to: "Newport", legIDs=[1,2,3], user=John, ...}
>
> LEGS TABLE:
>   leg: {id=1, from "New York", to "New Haven", seats = 3, rideID=1, ...}
>   leg: {id=2, from "New Haven", to "New London", seats = 3, rideID=1, ...}
>   leg: {id=3, from "New London", to "Newport", seats = 3, rideID=1, ...}

Then, when a passenger looks for a ride, you divide his journey into legs, and look for rides for these different legs, with a preference for legs that are part of the same ride.

Then, when booking a ride, you deduct a seat from each leg of the journey, whichever ride those legs belong to.

Comment: Nice approach, I did understand it much better now, thanks!